# Can't get rid of a warning in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out why my reset "Restart" button is not working properly because the incremented guessses and still going up. I also need to add a button that displays the correct number if someone gives up. Thanks for the help earlier guys with the warning, these are the two parts I am stuck on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Guessing Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><form action="game.php" method="POST">
Guess a number 1-100:<input type="text" name="userGuess"/>
<input type="submit" value="Guess"/>
<center><form action="game.php">
<input type="reset" value="Restart"/>
</form></center>
</body>
</html>

<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['randNum'] = isset($_SESSION['randNum']) ? $_SESSION['randNum'] : rand(0, 100);
$_SESSION['guesses'] = isset($_SESSION['guesses']) ? $_SESSION['guesses'] : 0;

$randNum = $_SESSION['randNum'];
$userGuess = $_POST['userGuess'];
$userGuess = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "userGuess");

if (isset($randNum)) {
    if ($userGuess<$randNum) {
            echo "<center>You guessed too low!</center>";
            $_SESSION['guesses']++;
            echo $_SESSION['guesses'];
        }
    if ($userGuess>$randNum) {
            echo "<center>You guessed too high!</center>";
            $_SESSION['guesses']++;
            echo $_SESSION['guesses'];
        }
    if ($userGuess==$randNum) {
            echo "<center>Congratulations You're right!!!</center>";
                         unset($_SESSION["randNum"], $_SESSION['guesses']);
    }
    if ($userGuess>100 || $userGuess<0) {
            echo "<center>Please enter a number betweeen 1 and 100!</center>";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Please enter a number between 1 and 100";
}

?>
```

Comment: simple: use a conditional statement for it . but this is failing you also `$userGuess = @userGuess;`

Comment: For some reason even user the error suppressing operant I am still getting the error when I first load up the page.

Answer (score 0):

When you visit the page for the first time, there's no POST data; it's pretty much just a normal request. However, when you submit the form, POST data is sent along with the request, and then `$_POST` contains `userGuess`.

Simply adding an `if (isset($_POST['userGuess']))` around your code should fix your problem:

```
if (isset($_POST['userGuess'])) {
    $userGuess = $_POST['userGuess'];
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use

```
if (filter_input(INPUT_POST, "userGuess") != null)
{

}
```

or

```
$userGuess = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "userGuess");
```

this sets $userGuess to null, not undefined;

**Update:**

Your counters are set in PHP(backend) you cannot reset these using a reset button and not reloading the page.

The answer for the result button is simple.
create button

```
<input type="button" value="Answer" onclick="Alert('<?php echo $randNum; ?>')" />
```

For the rest, do a little research...